# Pandas replace function - insert pad 0 to 3 numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

in Pandas (df), a column with following strings.  looking to pad 0 when number within string are <100

| Freq |
| --- |
| XXX100KHz |
| XYC200KHz |
| YYY80KHz |
| YYY50KHz |

to:

| Freq |
| --- |
| XXX100KHz |
| XYC200KHz |
| YYY**0**80KHz |
| YYY**0**50KHz |

following function doesn't work, as `\1` then `0` won't work as `\10` doesn't exist.

```
df.replace({'Freq':'^([A-Za-z]+)(\d\d[A-Za-z]*)$'},{'Freq':r'\1**0**\2'},regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df["Freq"] = df["Freq"].str.replace(
    r"(?<=\D)\d{1,2}(?=KHz)",
    lambda g: "{:0>3}".format(g.group()),
    regex=True,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        Freq
0  XXX100KHz
1  XYC200KHz
2  YYY080KHz
3  YYY050KHz
```

Comment: Actually, the input are very flexible.  it could be 80Mhz, that will needs to be changed to 080MHz, it could also be just 20 and needs to be changed to 020.  guess the first session of the regex should be ^([A-Za-z]*)

Comment: @Fred this is just implementation detail, but the core of the answer is the same ;) If you have specific issues in implementing it, then edit your question

Comment: Thanks, let me read up the group and ? function.  I am only using Python / Pandas sparsely and probably combined experience is <6 months.